# how to integrate an update feature into a nextjs supabase record?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am trying to make a list of db entries, with an edit button that loads a form to update the publication status of those entries. I can't figure out how to integrate that form with my list.

I have a list of db records as:

```
"use client"
import { createClientComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { updatePublicationStatusForm } from './updatePublicationStatusForm';


type FeedType = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    published: boolean;
    created_at: string;
    // ... any other fields that a publisher might have
};

export default function PendingPublicationList() {
    const [feeds, setFeeds] = useState<FeedType[]>([]);

    const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>();

    // Fetch publishers
    const fetchPendingPublications = async () => {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('feeds').select('id, title, published, created_at')
        .eq('published', false)
        .order('created_at');

        console.log("Fetch result:", data, error);

        if (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching publishers:", error);
        } else {
            setFeeds(data || []);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPendingPublications();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="w-full">
            <p className="text-lg text-dark pb-4 font-baron">awaiting publication</p>  


            {feeds.map(pp => (
                <div key={pp.id} className="pt-2">
                    <div className="capitalize text-sm text-dark font-baron">{pp.title} <span className="text-tip font-sans text-sm ml-2"> {dayjs(pp.created_at).format('DD MMMM YYYY')}</span>
                   
                    </div>
                    {/* // how can i add the update form here? */}
                </div>

            ))}

        </div>
    );
}
```

I have an update form as:

```
"use client"
import { createClientComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import advancedFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat';

dayjs.extend(advancedFormat);


import { updatePublicationStatus } from "./updatePublicatonStatusSubmit";

type Feeds = Database['public']['Tables']['feeds']['Row'];

export default function UpdatePublicationStatus({ feed }: { feed?: Feeds; }) {
  const [isPublished, setIsPublished] = useState(feed?.published || false);
  
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>()

 
  const handleFormSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget as HTMLFormElement);
    const selectedDate = formData.get("publicationDate") as string;
    const formattedDate = dayjs(selectedDate).format('Do MMMM YYYY'); 

    try {
      await updatePublicationStatus(formData);
      console.log("Feed updated successfully");
      // document.getElementById("formData").reset();

      // You can reset the form or redirect the user, etc. here
    } catch (error) {
      if (error && typeof error === 'object' && "message" in error) {
        console.error("Error from server action:", error.message);
    }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <div className="mb-2">
          <label className="mr-2">Confirmed for publication</label>

          <input
            name="published"
            className="cursor-pointer"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={isPublished}
            onChange={() => setIsPublished(prev => !prev)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-2">
          <label className="mb-2">Publication date</label>
          <input 
            name="publicationDate"
            type="date"
            className="bg-lighter border-none"
          />
        </div>
       
        <button type="submit" className="bg-linkStyle hover:bg-linkOnHover text-light my-4 py-2 px-4 rounded-none">Update publication status</button>
      </form>

      
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a submit action as:

```
"use server"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { createServerActionClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";

export const updatePublicationStatus = async (formData: FormData) => {
    const publicationDate = String(formData.get("publicationDate"));
    const published = Boolean(formData.has("published")) && formData.get("published") === 'on';
  
    // const supabase = createServerActionClient<Database>({ cookies });
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const supabase = createServerActionClient<Database>({ cookies: () => cookieStore });
    
    const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
  
    if (!user) throw new Error("No user found");
    // if (!title) throw new Error("Please enter a title");

    console.log("attempting to update publicationstatust feed", { formData });

    const { error } = await supabase
        .from("feeds")
        .update({ 
             published,  publicationDate  
        });
    if (error) throw new Error(error.message);
    
    revalidatePath("/");
}
```

How can I include the update form in the list of db entries?